# why my custom UITableviewCell can't call dealloc?

Tags: ios

```
static NSString *timeStr = @"MessageCellTime";
if (indexPath.row < [self.dataSource count]) {
    id obj = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        EMChatTimeCell *timeCell = (EMChatTimeCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:timeStr];
        if (timeCell == nil) {
            timeCell = [[EMChatTimeCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:timeStr];
            timeCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            timeCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            timeCell.textLabel.text = (NSString*)obj;

        });
        //timeCell.textLabel.text = (NSString*)obj;

        return timeCell;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageModel *model = (MessageModel*)obj;
        NSString *cellIndentifier = [EMChatViewCell cellIdentifierForMessageModel:model];
        EMChatViewCell *cell = (EMChatViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIndentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[EMChatViewCell alloc]initWithMessageModel:model reuseIdentifier:cellIndentifier];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }
    return cell;
```

ARC is enabled.They ViewController is call dealloc since I pop back,but my customCell such as EMChatTimecell and EMChatViewCell did not call it dealloc, Thanks to help me .

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a problem when you have a strong reference cycle. One of the possibilities can be that your delegate or dataSource objects are declared as strong instead of weak. 
Please read this -> [Apple memory management guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html). Even when using arc you should have a fair idea about memory management, it helps in tight situations like strong reference cycles.

Comment: Thanks to you reply.I know my cell did not dealloc maybe the reason which you said .But I just Can't find Where it happen.

Comment: Can you post some code of where you declared the delegate and data source? Or some other code that can be useful. Other cases can be where you are capturing self in a block. Post some code for more precise answer.

Comment: Due to the code is a lot ,I change the page,please click here.Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491866/currentviewcontroller-can-be-called-dealloc-but-it-tableviewcell-cant-be-call-d