# CurrentViewController can be called dealloc,but it tableViewCell can't be call dealloc?

Tags: ios

```
#pragma mark - createDataSource

-(NSMutableArray*)dataSource
{
    if (_dataSource == nil) {
        _dataSource = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return _dataSource;
}

#pragma mark - createTableView

-(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (!_tableView) {
        CGRect rect =self.view.frame;
        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(rect), CGRectGetHeight(rect)-64 - self.chatToolBar.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        _tableView.delegate = self;
        _tableView.dataSource = self;
        _tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc]init];
        _tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
        lpgr.minimumPressDuration = .5;
        //_tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        //_chatToolBar.alpha = 0;
        //[_tableView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
        //_tableView.bounces = NO;
    }
    return _tableView;
}

#pragma mark - dealloc in CurrentViewController

-(void)dealloc      //it be called when I use it's navigation pop back.
{
    _tableView.delegate = nil;
    _tableView.dataSource = nil;
    _tableView = nil;

    _slimeView.delegate = nil;
    _slimeView = nil;

    _chatToolBar.delegate = nil;
    _chatToolBar = nil;



    //清除当前聊天的用户
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


    appDelegate.currentChattingName = nil;

    [[EaseMob sharedInstance].chatManager stopPlayingAudio];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
    [[EaseMob sharedInstance].chatManager removeDelegate:self];
    [[[EaseMob sharedInstance] deviceManager]removeDelegate:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"kDXNotificationHeadImagePressed" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:kNOTIFICATION_REFRESHBACKBTNUNREADMESSAGECOUNT object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:kNOTIFICATION_CHATVIEW_SAVE_MESSAGECOUNT object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:LONGPRESSTEXTNOTIFICATION object:nil];


}

#pragma mark - When I use block


-(void)addChatDataToMessage:(EMMessage*)message
{
    __weak ChatViewController *weakSelf = self;   // sometimes I like use __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;  Is there have problem due to I use self.dataSource and self.tableView?

    dispatch_async(_messageQueue, ^{
        NSArray *messages = [weakSelf addChatToMessage:message];
        NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (int i = 0; i<messages.count; i++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(weakSelf.dataSource.count + i) inSection:0];
            [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //[weakSelf.tableView beginUpdates];
            [weakSelf.dataSource addObjectsFromArray:messages];
            [weakSelf.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            //[weakSelf.tableView endUpdates];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [weakSelf.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[indexPaths lastObject] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
                [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];

            });
        });
    });

    //[self scrollViewToBottom:YES];

}
```

Is there have problem I override self.tableView ?  I use block with weak self.I can't find where I make my Cell can't dealloc. My cells didn't use protocol too.Thanks for you read.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run a static analyser? Also can you paste the table view cell code here? Probably you are capturing tableViewCell in a retain cycle. Difficult to tell without tableViewCell code.